# Which technique to use to pass arbitrary string from template engine to JavaScript (or why do not use fake HTML attributed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jsp

No mutter which template engine used for my question.

I involved in project where find such code in JSP page:

```
<li class="clazz" attr="XXX">...</li>
```

and jQuery code which extract value from *attr* attribute:

```
$(".clazz").click(function () {
   var v = $(this).attr("attr");
   ...
}
```

Actually *XXX* is URL. I change JSP code to:

```
<li class="clazz"><a href="XXX">...</a></li>
```

and JS code to:

```
$(".clazz").click(function () {
   var v = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
   ...
}
```

Now I reach goal to have valid HTML.

Using fake tags simplify code but produce invalid HTML.

Is there easy way to pass data to JavaScript and preserve code simplicity?

Which technique to use to pass arbitrary string from template engine to JavaScript?

I assume that this data shouldn't rendered to user and expect that it shouldn't be based on CSS like by hiding data:

```
<span id="real-points-count" style="display:none">${param}
```

**UPDATE**. How is this code:

```
<div class="clazz" min="MINDATA" max="MAXDATA">...<>
```

can be transformed to carry *MINDATA* and *MAXDATA* to JavaScript in way to get valid **HTML5**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can work with HTML5, you can make use of `data-*` attributes which can let you add custom attributes to store data for an HTML element.

e.g.

```
<li class="clazz" data-myattr="XXX">...</li>
```

And then in JS'

```
$(".clazz").click(function () {
   var v = $(this).data("myattr");
   ...
}
```

References: [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*)*](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/), [jQuery HTML5 data- Attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

Comment: Exactly I want! +1 and accept. Reference to spec http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#attr-data

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try native javascript `onclick` for this.

Have a look at this ..

```
<li class="clazz" onclick="myFunction('my_url')">...</li>
```

and then write this function which accepts your URL as input .. i.e ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(inUrl) {
    ....
};
</script>
```

This way you can maintain the valid HTML and avoid the fake tags.

NOTE: You can pass any no. of parameters to the function, even the element itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With this approach you dont really need html5 support. As it is simple native javascript, it works with all browsers.